# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I could not able to submit the form through javascript function. I have a requirement when user clicks on a link, i need to submit a form. Below is the error seen on browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined
```

Please suggest how can i submit the form to invoke the spring controller method.

Below is the javascript function:

```
function submitDataOnClick(){
    document.myForm.action = contextPath + "/dataProcess.htm";
    document.myForm.submit();
}
<body>
<form name="myForm">
//all form elements..
<table class="myClass">
     <tr><td><a href="" onclick="submitDataOnClick()"> </a></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dataProcess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView dataProcess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            BindingResult beException)
            throws IOException {

//logic...
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("home");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Use `id` and `getElementById()`, direct reference to elements via `document` has been deprecated for a decade ago.

Comment: You have to pass a reference to myForm in your function. Or as the first commenter stated you can get myForm with getElementById()

Comment: @Teemu Although it's deprecated, it should still work. Any idea why he's getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar No idea, OP's code seems to work in FF [as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/h25gutef/).

Answer (score 3):

In most browsers, that should work **provided** you don't have a `var myForm` at global scope anywhere or something like that. The reason is that when you give a `form` element a `name` attribute, the browser will create a property on `document` using that name that refers to the `form`. But if you use that same name on something else, it can conflict with the one you think you're using.

Three options for working around that:

1. You've tagged your question `jquery` but don't appear to be using jQuery in your code, so a non-jQuery option:

   If you want to use a link to submit the form, one option is to give the form an `id` and then use that to look it up:

   HTML:

   ```
   <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
   ```

   *(remove `name=...` if you don't need it)*

   JavaScript:

   ```
   function submitDataOnClick(){
       var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
       form.action = contextPath + "/dataProcess.htm";
       form.submit();
   }
   ```
2. Since you *did* tag `jquery`, a *minimal-change* jQuery option:

   HTML:

   ```
   <tr><td><a href="" onclick="submitDataOnClick($(this).closest('form')[0])"> </a></td></tr>
   ```

   JavaScript:

   ```
   function submitDataOnClick(form){
       form.action = contextPath + "/dataProcess.htm";
       form.submit();
   }
   ```
3. ...or a bigger-changes solution: Get rid of the `onclick` on the link entirely and perhaps add a class to those links:

   ```
   <tr><td><a href="" class="submit-on-click"> </a></td></tr>
   ```

   ...and put this code in a `script` element after the form (usual recommendation is at the very bottom, just before the closing `</body>` tag):

   ```
   $("form[name=myForm]").on("click", "a.submit-on-click", function() {
       var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];
       form.action = contextPath + "/dataProcess.htm";
       form.submit();
   });
   ```

Comment: I'm still facing the issue, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of null. Please find my complete example in http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/37/ . Anyways in fiddle could not able to see the above mentioned exception. @T.J. Crowder. Please suggest where i'm wrong.

Comment: @user222: Well, if you don't see it in the fiddle, then you need to see what's different between the fiddle and your code.